# Merging multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this list which contains three arrays:

```
[
    array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object), 
    array([4, 5, 6], dtype=object), 
    array([7, 8, 9], dtype=object)
]
```

And i would like to turn it into something like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

or something like this:

```
([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
```

But it seems like I can't use for example `np.concatenate` to merge them. Is it because of the `dtype=object`?

Comment: what is `array()` from, what module

Comment: `np.concatenate` *does* work. If it's not working for you, please show us how you're using it and why the output is wrong (or what error you get). Read more on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error using `dtype=object` and `array = np.array`. `concatenate` works just fine

Comment: I must have made a mistake because now it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.concatenate()` or `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`, both should flatten your array:

```
import numpy as np
# from itertools import chain

arr = [np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object), np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype=object), np.array([7, 8, 9], dtype=object)]

print(np.concatenate(arr))
# or print(list(chain.from_iterable(arr)))
# [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

If you need second output in question:

```
tuple(list(x) for x in arr)
# ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.concatenate` will work for your case:

```
>>> np.concatenate([array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object), array([4, 5, 6], dtype=object), array([7, 8, 9], dtype=object)])
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=object)

>>>list(_)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If for some reason it doesn't, please provide exception you're getting

Answer (score 1):

To flatten the list of arrays

```
from numpy import array
temp=[array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object), array([4, 5, 6], dtype=object), array([7, 8, 9], dtype=object)]
numpy.array(temp).flatten() #array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=object)
```

To further convert it into a list

```
numpy.array(temp).flatten().tolist() #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you need list of list

```
from numpy import array
temp=[array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object), array([4, 5, 6], dtype=object), array([7, 8, 9], dtype=object)]
[x.tolist() for x in temp]
```

Or

```
tuple(x.tolist() for x in temp) #([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```